# Adding additional host to Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, virtualhost, website

I have been tasked to add a copy of an existing website to the setup. (To be used as a test environment)

The existing setup consists of :
a.mysite.com
b.mysite.com
c.mysite.com

I've been trying to add d.mysite.com but with no luck ..
Setup:
Debian 5.0
What I've done so far;
copied the config file in /etc/apache2/sites-available of c.mysite.com
Renamed name of file, ServerAdmin, ServerName, ServerAlias, DocumentRoot and the Directory to point to the new website's location.

ServerAdmin me@work.com
        ServerName d.mysite.com
        ServerAlias d.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite_d/
        php_value error_reporting 6135
        
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        
        
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

Ran the command a2ensite succesfully
Checked and verified that a sym link is present in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
It links to the config file of d.mysite.com in /etc/apache2/sites-available
Reloaded and restarted Apache2

Result:
The new website is not accessible, Chrome gives the typical 'Oops! Google Chrome can not find d.mysite.com'

Additional info:
The other websites are working fine, for example c.mysite.com is accessible.

I really think I'm missing something very basic here.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to create a DNS record for d.mysite.com.

Comment: Could you elaborate where this should be done ?

Comment: @Gnagy - This is a site for professionals. As such, we expect people to be able to do a modicum or research on their own. Look into your DNS hosting situation and read about DNS in General and things should become clear.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple.
I had to add an A record to the DNS management section on the admin panel of our domain name provider.

I was searching in the wrong place.

Comment: In fact, you are correct. Will update to reflect this.